# How to implement a seen feature in Android using firebase database

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database - https://ibb.co/bWHzmy

I'm not getting on how to set the seen = false to seen true... I mean it has to do with onstart/oncreate of the chat activity... but i obviously want the seen feature to come only below the other users text just like on any messaging app... Can anyone help me out on how to achieve that

Saving Message

```
private void sendMessage() {
    String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't Send Blank Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        String message_sender_ref = "Messages/" + MessageSenderId + "/" + MessageRecieverId;
        String message_reciver_ref = "Messages/" + MessageRecieverId + "/" + MessageSenderId;

        Map messageTextBody = new HashMap<>();
        messageTextBody.put("Message", messageText);
        messageTextBody.put("Seen", false);
        messageTextBody.put("Type", "Text");
        messageTextBody.put("Time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        messageTextBody.put("From", MessageSenderId);

        DatabaseReference user_message_key = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).push();
        String message_push_id = user_message_key.getKey();

        Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();
        messageBodyDetails.put(message_sender_ref + "/" + message_push_id, messageTextBody);
        messageBodyDetails.put(message_reciver_ref + "/" + message_push_id, messageTextBody);

        mDatabaseReference.updateChildren(messageBodyDetails, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    Log.d("Chat_Log", databaseError.getMessage().toString());
                }
                messageArea.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Retrieving message

```
private void fetchMessages() {
    mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Messages message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
            messagesList.add(message);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You haven't used `onDisconnect()` method in your code at all, as Frank van Puffelen explained in his answer.

Comment: That's there in the onStart method... but how will onDisconnect help with Read reciept

Comment: There is no `onDisconnect()` in your code. `how will onDisconnect help with Read reciept?` Please read again that answer because it contains all necessary informations.